# Getting script error in ATL project when I add a method to interface in VS2015 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2015, atl

I am getting exception in ATL project when I try to add a method to the interface using Visual studio 2015 IDE.

Error1

[image: Error1]

Error2

[image: Error2]

I am using below VS2015 IDE version.

Thanks.

Comment: You can find my attached sample program here [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArdounX--7yPsh8n4RW7IRCTPKy8)

Comment: The above error is same as in given link [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1056839/atl-code-wizard-add-method-failes-due-to-script-error)